# Can Dev Tools freeze a splash page that only loads for a few seconds?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Looked around and didn't see answer. I need to work on a splash page that is only visible for 5 seconds. Here's what I've tried:

1. Disable Javascript. That broke the whole thing.
2. From Source, hitting pause. This let's me see the page as long as I want and even effect some styles, but only some. Seems like a partial solution.

Is there a straightforward solution for this?

thanks!

Comment: It depends on the code, but if you find the redirect or exiting line of code in Javascript, you could put a breakpoint on or before that line in order to pause execution. You can do that by opening the chrome dev tools, clicking on sources, finding the code and then clicking on the line number to set a breakpoint.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. I don't control the javascript source so that might be tricky. I'll try that if there isn't a more straightforward option. Thanks.